# Can't locate a button by any command in Java in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I tried different commands and none of them works. I want to find and click "Wykup składkę" button.
I'm working on:
- **Firefox 45.3.0 esr**
- **selenium webdriver 2.53.0**
- **TestNG**

Here's html code:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <section class="card skladki">
                <h2> Składki </h2>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <!--template bindings={}-->
                </div>
                <div class="button-container text-xs-center">

                    <a class="btn btn-sheer btn-card" href="#/feetable">Wykup składkę</a>
                    <!--template bindings={}--><a class="btn btn-sheer btn-card" href="#/fees-list">Lista składek</a>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
```

And my test script

```
package testy;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class wykup_skladek_olatest {
public WebDriver driver;

@BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.navigate().to("http://dev.wedkarz.pzw.pl/#/login");}
@Test
public void f() throws InterruptedException {
  driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("****");
  driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("****");
  driver.findElement(By.tagName("button")).click();
  driver.navigate().to("http://dev.wedkarz.pzw.pl/#/login");
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Wykup")).click();
  }


@AfterMethod
public void afterMethod() throws InterruptedException {
      driver.quit();
      System.out.println("Wykupowanie składki - Test zakończony    powodzeniem"); 
      }}
```

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: "Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a.btn.btn-sheer.btn-card"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.button-container [href='#/feetable']")).click();
```

BUT,

I wanted to locate and click with this method another button and it DOESN't work. What kind of dark magic is it?

Answer (score 1):

You should *wait* for the element to be present on screen. Its taking some time for `By.id("username")` to be present on screen and you are trying to access that before its present.

> You can use the following code :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id<locator>));
```

Edit : 
     To click on `<a class="btn btn-sheer btn-card" href="#/feetable">Wykup składkę</a>`

You can try :

```
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.btn.btn-sheer.btn-card")).click();
```

Comment: But I don't have any problem with loggin in. Webdriver can't click on the last button.

Comment: It works, thank you. I'm surprised, because I thought I used almost every method.

Comment: Of course I did it, but I'm not permited to do that before having '15' of reputation.

Comment: I don't know why, but it doesn't work now. "Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a.btn.btn-sheer.btn-card"

Comment: check if the element is present before performing the operation on it

Comment: not sure if I'm doing it good. I added that script:

if(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a.btn.btn-sheer.btn-card")).size() != 0){
    System.out.println("Element is Present");
    }else{
    System.out.println("Element is Absent");
    }

But none of those gives any echo in console. TestNG shows that test ran well.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different selector. I wouldn't be a fan of the css selector.

Try this -

1. Right click on the element on the page that you want to select.
2. Click on inspect element
3. When the HTML is highlighted for that element, right click on html and click copy --> xpath .
4. Then use the driver to find the element by xpath. For an example on this page e.g. the add comment button this would look like

   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='add-comment-39636086']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input"));

**Edit**
So with the button xpath you provided this is how I would write it:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/app/main/dashboard/section/div/div[1]/div[1]/sect‌​ion/div[2]/a[1]"));
element.click();
```

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work, too. Maybe I'm doing sth wrong. That's the button's xpath: /html/body/app/main/dashboard/section/div/div[1]/div[1]/section/div[2]/a[1]. How should I type it?

Comment: This error occured:
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector /html/body/app/main/dashboard/section/div/div[1]/div[1]/sectâ€Śâ€‹ion/div[2]/a[1] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression /html/body/app/main/dashboard/section/div/div[1]/div[1]/sectâ€Śâ€‹ion/div[2]/a[1] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.
Command duration or timeout: 70 milliseconds

Comment: Go to your project properties and make sure that you're encoding is set to UTF-8

Comment: It is now. But still selenium can't find the button.